# TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function in my react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

React Navigation version is 4.
Can we return state as component, i am refactoring from class to functional is it possible? because in class components return statement was <this.state.appcontainer /> [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-wildflower-vfr87b?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Could any one help it out

Comment: The code in your link is correct, just by looking. I think the error is from somewhere else. Can you please share more logs?

Comment: @AdhithyanS can you share more code and other files too, cant see whats causing the issue here